# Information to display in a dialog box not another page

Tags: php, jquery, html

How can I make each button instead of going to another page to display the information on a dialog box in the same page. 
This code here is in the head to call the id from the other file

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getvoucher(id){


    return data;

    });

    }

</script>
```

Then I have this button in my while loop:

```
<td><?php echo $row['voucher_id']; ?></td>
<td> <?php echo'<a href="test.php?id=' . $row['voucher_id'] . '"> Click here</a>'; ?></td>
```

When I click on the button it displays what I want in test but instead I want it to show in a dialog box, any help?

Comment: You can use any jquery ui dialog to make popup and show your data in it.

Comment: I know how to do a dialog box but i'm unsure how to get the data that's inside test to show

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on("click","td",function(){
  
    
   $("#data").empty();
   $("#data").append(


   );
   $("#data").dialog( {width:700});
 });
});

Comment: how about bootstrap dialog?

Comment: jQuery UI Dialog, [the documentation is here](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#id").click(function() {
     $.get("http://inactive/test.php?id=" + id, function(data,status){

        $("#content").html(data);

     });
});
```

Comment: Do I need to add the whole site or like you did?

Comment: Yeah the whole site but I guess you have yours deleted.

Answer (score 1):

you can use JQuery's UI dialog which is pretty widely used today. Here is the link for demo:

> https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

What you can do is to set the content you want to display in the dialog div's

tag and then bind the dialog to the button id.

**Example**

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("#voucher_id").click(function() {
     $.get("http://52.91.139.19/inactive/test.php?id=" + id, function(data,status){

        $("#content").html(data);

     });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p id="content">This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but I mean how can i display contents of another page in it?

Comment: @jasmine825 it is quite simple, if you have the page's data then just add it to the html dialog tag. I will update my code with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You should then put Id on button and in script

```
$("#id").click(function(){
    alert("You clicked the button");
});
```

Did you try with alert something like this echo `<script>alert("Message");</script>`;

Or did you try to open fancybox you can use for example `<a class="className" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="yourhreftodisplayinfoonfancybox">Open</a>`

```
<script>
$(".className").fancybox({
    maxWidth:500,
    maxHeight:600,
    fitToView:false,
    width:'60%',
    height:'100%'
}
});</script>`
```

If you want on button then try with onclick to rised fancybox or dialog I don't do like that

Comment: I know you are short of reps, but this is really just a comment. This type of  answer attracts downvotes
___I did not DV___ and if that happens you will loose rep points and take longer to get to 50 reps. Until you have 50 reps stick to questions that are well asked and therefore easily answered without needing clarification. Maybe you should delete this comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly instead of downgrading people's answers, you could actually show some help

Comment: I did not **downgrade** your **comment** In fact it seems you have taken my advice and attempted to **UPGRADED** your comment into an answer. _So mission accomplished_ I help where I can!

Comment: But unfortunately OP wants a **dialog** and not an alert, so this is still not very useful to the OP or SO

Comment: I try to help you can do it with fancybox or dialog

Comment: Based on what OP is asking I would guess they want the dialog to appear automatically and not for the user to have to click a link, but edit by edit we are getting closer to an anaswer to the question

Comment: You can make link to look almost as button with css :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Actually, I have a link that when a person clicks on it I want a dialog to appear with the information of theres that is in test.php, through their voucher_id

Comment: @jasmine825 then do like I said fancybox looks better just insert jquery on your page and download fancybox insert fancybox.css

Comment: @RiggsFolly any idea how I can call my dialog box to display when i click the button?

Comment: @jasmine825 in your code you have <a href do it with link just make some css to look like button :)

Comment: @jhony3 yeah but how can I call the dialog box instead of test.php

Comment: I would that that as I wrote with fancybox when you press on link fancybox should popup and what you put in test.php should be shown in fancybox dialog, for example, picture, form, text, anything is more useful then dialogbox

Comment: @jasmine825 if you want with fancybox you must download fancybox package insert somewhere in your project then put jquery reference in your head page and fancybox.pack.js and also fancybox.css and then do it like I wrote in answer <a class and so on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120125/discussion-between-jasmine825-and-jhony3).